# Update Cron expression runtime in SpringBoot @Scheduled

Tags: spring-boot, scheduling

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class CustomScheduler {

    @Autowired
    private IAppUpdateService appUpdateService;
    

    
    @Scheduled(cron = "#{@appUpdateService.findCroExpById()}")
    public void job1() {
        System.out.println(new Date());
    }
}
```

Above snippet dosent work properly as expected is there any way to achieve this or any other approach is available!!!

1. I want to achieve like to retrieve cron expression from db at runtime.
2. User may change cron timing through UI,thats why i want to fetch it through service.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bean to get the values from database and use the bean in the corn. Detailed example is in the link :

http://mbcoder.com/dynamic-task-scheduling-with-spring/

Comment: Umesh Sanwal  (Bean) usage is working fine and if i change cron expression in database is not getting updated. I will check it, even though if you get any idea please update :)

Comment: Yeah with the @Scheduler it will always use the first value which was fetched from the db , looks like you will have to write your own scheduler for your implementation. Here is a code example: https://github.com/mustafabayar/DynamicSchedulingTutorial